# Existence of non-trivial kernel in Schur's lemma for matrix representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

**Theorem:** Let $T:G\rightarrow GL(V)$ and $S:G\rightarrow GL(U)$ be two irreducible representation of a finite group $G$. If a matrix $A$ is such that $AT(g)=S(g)A\:\forall g\in G$, then either $A=0$ or $A$ is invertible square matrix and hence the two representations are equivalent.

**Solution:** Suppose $T$ is $n$ dimensional and $S$ is $m$ dimensional. First we note that $A$ is $m\times n$. Suppose, $\exists$ a subspace $W\subset V$ such that $Aw=0$ iff $w\in W$.

For any linear transformation matrix $P$ on the subspace $W\subset V$, $AP=0$. It follows that, $AT(g)P=S(g)AP=0$. But, $AT(g)P=0 \stackrel{1}{\implies} T(g)Pw\in W\:\forall w\in W \stackrel{2}{\implies} T(g)w\in W\:\forall w\in W$.

This mean that $W$ is a $T$-invariant subspace. since the representations are irreducible, the only possible invariant subspaces are $W=\{0\}$ or $W=V$. If $W=V$ then $Av=0\:\forall v\in V\implies A=0$.

If $W=\{0\}$, then $Av\neq 0$ for any nonzero $v\in V$. We can redo the same argument by starting with a subspace $W'\in U$ such that $uA=0$ iff $u\in W'$.

> Why we choose left action for $U$, $uA$?

Following the same steps we can prove that either $A=0$ or $uA\neq 0$ for any $u\in U$.

So, we are left with 2 cases: either $A=0$ or $Av$ and $uA$ are never $0$ for any nonzero $u\in U,v\in V$. We just have to prove that the second case implies that $A$ is an invertible square matrix.

If the number of rows is less then the number of columns, there must exists a $v\in V$ such that $Av=0$ which is a contradiction. $$\therefore m\geq n\tag1$$
similarly, If the number of columns is less then the number of rows, there must exists a $u\in U$ such that $uA=0$ which is a contradiction. $$\therefore m\leq n\tag2$$
$(1)$ and $(2)$ implies $m=n$.

> The existence of such $u\in U$ and $v\in V$ is not clear to me.

Finally, we know that a square matrix has non trivial kernel iff its determinant is $0$. A must have non-zero determinant.

---

I couldn't manage to understand the in-between logic I highlight above.

To be honest I couldn't manage to understand this theorem intuitively, like a connected logics to write the proof by own (after understanding once). It will be great help if anyone enlighten me the intuition.